# Cloud9 IDE kills activator when compiling

Tags: playframework-2.0, cloud9-ide, typesafe-activator

I've been trying to run my Play! project on Cloud9 IDE. However it keeps killing `activator` before it could `start`

```
tabdulradi@my-project:~/workspace (master) $ ./activator
[info] Loading project definition from /home/ubuntu/workspace/project
[info] Set current project to my-project (in build file:/home/ubuntu/workspace/)
[my-project] $ start -Dhttp.port=8080
[info] Compiling 9 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /home/ubuntu/workspace/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[info] Main Scala API documentation to /home/ubuntu/workspace/target/scala-2.10/api...
[info] CoffeeScript compiling on 5 source(s)
[info] LESS compiling on 1 source(s)
[info] Wrote /home/ubuntu/workspace/target/scala-2.10/my-project_2.10-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
Killed
```

I tried to run only `compile` hoping I can split that execution into smaller parts, so C9-IDE won't kill it. However it was also killed

```
tabdulradi@my-project:~/workspace (master) $ ./activator compile
[info] Loading project definition from /home/ubuntu/workspace/project
[info] Set current project to my-project (in build file:/home/ubuntu/workspace/)
[info] Compiling 9 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /home/ubuntu/workspace/target/scala-2.10/classes...
Killed
```

However, running `run` runs the server successfully, but then killed when the first request come to the server (i.e: starts to compile)

```
tabdulradi@my-project:~/workspace (master) $ ./activator
[info] Loading project definition from /home/ubuntu/workspace/project
[info] Set current project to my-project (in build file:/home/ubuntu/workspace/)
[my-project] $ run -Dhttp.port=8080

--- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8080

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

[info] Compiling 9 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /home/ubuntu/workspace/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[info] LESS compiling on 1 source(s)
[info] CoffeeScript compiling on 5 source(s)
Killed
```

Is it possible to configure Cloud9 IDE to tolerate with activator? Or at least configure activator/sbt to limit CPU consumption so that Cloud9IDE won't kill it?

Answer (score 4):

Most likely your box went out of memory. You can check if your process was killed for that reason using "dmesg". Free accounts currently get 512 MB, while premium users get 1024 MB.